# $x\leq y \rightarrow x\vee(y\wedge z) \leq y\wedge(x\vee z)$

Tags: lattice-orders

every lattice satisfies $x\leq y \rightarrow x\vee(y\wedge z) \leq y\wedge(x\vee z)$.

My proof:

$x\leq y, x\leq (x\vee z)\Rightarrow x\leq y\wedge(x\vee z)$

$(y\wedge z)\leq y,z$ and $x,z\leq (x\vee z) \Rightarrow (y\wedge z)\leq (x\vee z)$

$(y\wedge z)\leq y, (y\wedge z)\leq (x\vee z)\Rightarrow (y\wedge z)\leq y\wedge(x\vee z)$

$x\vee(y\wedge z) \leq y\wedge(x\vee z)$

is this proof correct or it's not clear and I missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is Ok, but it's actually simpler (or cleaner, in my opinion) with the following approach.

If $x \leq y$ then
$$x \vee (y \wedge z) \leq y \vee (y \wedge z) = y.$$
I suppose you're familiar with absorption, which is valid in all lattices:
$$x \vee (x \wedge y)=x 
\quad\text{and}\quad
x \wedge (x\vee y)=x.$$
Now we need to show that $x\vee (y \wedge z) \leq x \vee z$.
But since $y \wedge z \leq z$,
$$x \vee (y\wedge z)\leq x\vee z.$$

Comment: Thank you, amrsa